# terminal tool (linux) for repair corrupted zip files

Tags: linux, terminal, zip, repair

I've a corrupt zip file. I've tried to repair it with

```
zip -F file.zip
```

and

```
zip -FF file.zip
```

but was not successful. Is there another terminal tool under Linux for repairing?

Comment: Maybe the file is FUBR?

Comment: Tfw you thought you made a backup and nuked an eMac hard drive for untold shenanigans, but you never copied that file to your main machine and the filesystem on the USB drive gets corrupted. Take time to ensure your backups are good folks! Thankfully I only lost an old iTunes library.

Answer (score 143):

try this

```
zip -FF Corrupted.zip --out New.zip
```

This will scan the corrupted zip archive and make a new one eliminating the errors.

As a result you will get a new zip file. Then simply run this command.

```
unzip New.zip
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Doing it this way didn't really give me a working zip-file, running the command again over the new zip file did do the trick. It was a desperate move, didn't expect it to work.

Comment: Worked great on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS~ Context: my zip was created on Windows 10, uploaded to OneDrive, and downloaded in Ubuntu. Zip worked on Windows but not on Ubuntu but the answer fixed the issue.

Comment: Saved the day, Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: @Desi: AWESOME (MacOS 11.6.1) many thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Just referenced this question in my answer to a similar one - [Linux Mint 12 - how to open a .zip file in terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/699385/linux-mint-12-how-to-open-a-zip-file-in-terminal/699490#699490)

It is worth adding here what the zip manual currently says about the difference between -F and -FF:

> The single -F is more reliable if the archive is not too much damaged, so try this option first.

So the first attempt would be:

```
zip -F broken.zip --out fixed.zip
unzip fixed.zip
```

And if that doesn't work:

```
zip -FF broken.zip --out fixed.zip
unzip fixed.zip
```

Answer (score 12):

I recently encountered a .zip file that neither `zip -F file.zip` nor `zip -FF file.zip` could fix. However,

```
7z x file.zip
```

was able to extract all the files. Hence, trying out [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) could be a good idea. If needed, you can then pack the extracted files into a new archive.

Comment: This worked for me when unzipping an archive created on Windows, where `zip` was unable to recognize the beginning of the file and gave up, while `7z` reported `Header errors` and then proceeded to extract the 11 GB+ zip successfully.

Comment: Worked great on partial zip archive.

Comment: And p7Zip appears to be a fork of 7-zip https://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 6):

[DiskInternals ZIP Repair](http://www.diskinternals.com/zip-repair/) works perfectly under Wine it's saved me in the past.

Comment: You can also just extract the actual executable from the installer using 7-Zip. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of a program that will do a better job repairing the archive though.

You might try

```
unzip -vt file.zip
```

just to see if maybe you can extract some of the files safely, or figure out which files in the archive are corrupt.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but i get the same result as with "zip -F" :(

Answer (score 0):

Due to permission errors, a ZIP process of mine crashed consistently before moving the temporary ZIP file into the final ZIP file.

The result was a folder full of temporary files named `zi<random>`, e.g. `zi0Be571a`.

`zip -F` did not work, nor did `zip -FF`, `7z x`, `ziprecover`. The error was that the file did not contain a central directory.

On Windows, WinRAR gave an error but did display the (partial) file contents.

DiskInternals ZipRecover was able to scan the temporary file and reconstruct the central directory, yielding a perfectly recovered Zip file.

Answer (score 0):

The man page of `zip` explains:

> The -FF option may create an inconsistent archive.  Depending on what is damaged, you can then use the -F option to fix that
> archive.

So, you run:

```
zip -FF damaged.zip --out fix1.zip
zip -F fix1.zip --out fix2.zip
unzip fix2.zip
```

This approach worked for my damaged zip file.